# Making all possible combinations per group in Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a very big CSV file with 122290 rows. It is order as follow:

```
Feature, Person
Fever, Pat1
Headache, Pat1
Burping, Pat1
Fever, Pat2
Obese, Pat2
Headache, Pat2
Jaundice, Pat2
```

I would like to make a new table. This table is a combination of the features per patient... I want to look if certain symptoms show clustering of occurence. I did this with Python, with the csv.reader. But because it was looping all the time, it takes several houres for 122290 rows. Every patient has approx. 305 symptoms... There are 405 patients. I don't want duplicates like Feature1 == Feature2... I was wondering if this is also possible in Pandas... And if so, can you line out how you would start to tackle this problem? Thank you!

```
Feature1, Feature2, Person
Fever, Headache, Pat1
Fever, Burping, Pat1
Heache, Burping, Pat1
Fever, Obese, Pat2
Fever, Headache, Pat2
Fever, Jaundice, Pat2
Obese, Headache, Pat2
Obese, Jaundice, Pat2
Headache, Jaundice, Pat2
```

Comment: do you want a 405 x 305 matrix with either 1 or 0 in every cell?

Comment: I finally will have a matrix with 3 columns and millions of rows. I don't want to use a matrix.... this will result in a lot of 0s in the matrix and a lot of memory usage, because I want to do statistics on these combinations...

Answer (score 3):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).  You can do a self-merge of the DataFrame with itself, then remove the  extra pairs (where features are reversed or paired with themselves).

```
df2 = pandas.merge(df, df, on='Person', suffixes=['1', '2'])
df2 = df2[df2.Feature1 < df2.Feature2]
```

Result:

```
Person  Feature1  Feature2
Pat1       Fever  Headache
Pat1     Burping     Fever
Pat1     Burping  Headache
Pat2       Fever     Obese
Pat2       Fever  Headache
Pat2       Fever  Jaundice
Pat2    Headache     Obese
Pat2    Headache  Jaundice
Pat2    Jaundice     Obese
```